# Sql Server Temporal table history

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, temporal-tables

Is there a way to identify deleted rows in history from the table?

So when I perform an updated or a delete it moves data to the history, I want to know which rows in history were deleted

help

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`output`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) clause.  For example:

```
declare @ids table (id int);

delete from t
    output deleted.id into @ids
    where . . .;

select *
from @ids;
```

Comment: I want to do it in Temporal table, not just while/after deleting.

Answer (score 0):

Use a semi-anti join between the temporal table and the history table based on the PK.

Comment: How will that tell me if the row was deleted?

Comment: Only deleted rows will appear in the query result dataset. If you want more detail, please post the DDL of your table with the temporal design and I will give you the query...

Answer (score 0):

As an example...

```
CREATE SCHEMA _CHRONO;
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.TEMPO
(
ID          INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
SOME_DATA   VARCHAR(32),
_DH_DEB     DATETIME2 GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW START HIDDEN NOT NULL,
_DH_FIN     DATETIME2 GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW END   HIDDEN NOT NULL,
PERIOD FOR SYSTEM_TIME (_DH_DEB, _DH_FIN)
)
WITH (SYSTEM_VERSIONING = ON (HISTORY_TABLE = _CHRONO.TEMPO));
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.TEMPO VALUES ('a data'), ('another data')
GO

DELETE FROM dbo.TEMPO WHERE SOME_DATA LIKE '%other%'
GO
```

And now the query retrieving deleted rows :

```
SELECT CT.*
FROM   _CHRONO.TEMPO AS CT
       LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.TEMPO AS T
          ON CT.ID = T.ID
```

retrieving the last version of the deleted rows needs to add some extra SQL conditions

Comment: What is I do an update (UPDATR dbo.TEMPO  SET SOME_DATA= 'another kind of data' WHERE SOME_DATA='another data'), this will also create a row in  _CHRONO.TEMPO

Comment: What I was hoping that SQL Server will have something ( like ROW_NUMBER() ) to identify the operation which made the data to be moved to history

Comment: by nature RDBMS will have only what you designed to. This is a general conformance rule due to the creator of RDBMS, F. E. Codd. Despite this fact certain RDBMS do have hidden colums which is a fine mess (Oracle and PostGreSQL as an example) ...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know which rows were deleted in history, just create an audit table and have a trigger in the real table.

For example, you have a table called "PeopleTbl".

1- You will create an audit table to store the history of "PeopleTbl". Let's create a table called "PeopleAuditTbl".

The structure of the "PeopleAuditTbl". Should have all the columns that you wish to keep track of and a time field and a TypeField(Delete, Inserted, or Updated).

2- Now in your "PeopleTbl". You will create a trigger that stores updated or delete (You can also store inserted records if you want.

The trigger for delete should be something like this.

```sql
ALTER TRIGGER T_PeopleTbl
    ON PeopleTbl
    AFTER DELETE
AS
INSERT INTO PeopleAuditTbl(
        //Fields you want to store
        Date,
        TypeField
    )
    SELECT
        //Fields you want to store
        GETDate(),
        'DELETE'
    FROM DELETED
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to use your Temporal History table to identify the records that have been deleted from the Main table, the following example demonstrates how this can be achieved:

```
-- Create a Temporal Table for demonstration purposes
CREATE TABLE dbo.Invoice
(
  InvoiceId int identity(1,1) PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
  , InvoiceDate date NOT NULL
  -- Other fields...
  , SysStartTime datetime2 GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW START
  , SysEndTime datetime2 GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW END
  , PERIOD FOR SYSTEM_TIME (SysStartTime, SysEndTime)
 )
WITH (SYSTEM_VERSIONING = ON (HISTORY_TABLE = dbo.InvoiceHistory));
go

-- Create some dummy data
insert into Invoice(InvoiceDate) values ('2020-01-01'),('2020-02-01')
go
WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:03'
go
delete from Invoice where InvoiceId=1
go

-- Get Current Records
select * from Invoice

-- Get Deleted Records
;with cte as
(
    select InvoiceId, MAX(SysEndTime) [SysEndTime]
    from Invoice FOR SYSTEM_TIME ALL
    group by InvoiceId
    having MAX(SysEndTime) < '9999-12-31'
)
select i.*
from Invoice FOR SYSTEM_TIME ALL i
inner join cte c on (i.InvoiceId=c.InvoiceId and i.SysEndTime=c.SysEndTime)
```

Basically, we're looking at the union of the main and history tables (*select * from Invoice FOR SYSTEM_TIME ALL*) for any records where the **latest** version is no longer valid (*MAX(SysEndTime) < '9999-12-31'*)